# Using sed to replace next two occurences of the pipe character

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having trouble finding `sed` options to replace the next two occurrences of a character after a string match. Basically, in these CSV files, I'm trying to replace the first 2 immediate pipe `|` characters after `jobcd` is matched, because it should be one field.

I was able to run this, before I realized this replaced every single `|` character... `sed -i 's/|/%/g' data.csv`

Here's a sample row from these csv files:

```
-1|7149636|2015-02-14 00:42:23|20150214|4223||Delete Future Batch||jobcd: %PAL| Cnt:60|||1900-01-01 00:00:00|0|||0||||0|0|0|.000
```

I'm trying to get that row to look like:

```
-1|7149636|2015-02-14 00:42:23|20150214|4223||Delete Future Batch||jobcd: %PAL% Cnt:60%||1900-01-01 00:00:00|0|||0||||0|0|0|.000
```

Edit: instead of `%`, I'm trying to replace with `\|` so I'm trying to get output to look like:

```
-1|7149636|2015-02-14 00:42:23|20150214|4223||Delete Future Batch||jobcd: %PAL\| Cnt:60\|||1900-01-01 00:00:00|0|||0||||0|0|0|.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s='-1|7149636|2015-02-14 00:42:23|20150214|4223||Delete Future Batch||jobcd: %PAL| Cnt:60|||1900-01-01 00:00:00|0|||0||||0|0|0|.000'

sed -E 's/(\|jobcd)([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|/\1\2\\|\3\\|/g' <<< "$s"
-1|7149636|2015-02-14 00:42:23|20150214|4223||Delete Future Batch||jobcd: %PAL\| Cnt:60\|||1900-01-01 00:00:00|0|||0||||0|0|0|.000
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I should use a replacement string of `\|` instead of `%`. I tried `sed -i -E 's/(\|jobcd)([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|/\1\2\|\3\|/g'` but that didn't work. What would be the proper syntax?

Comment: You need to doubly escape the \ by using `sed -E 's/(\|jobcd)([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|/\1\2\\|\3\\|/g' <<< "$s"`